# Is it possible to save the active shader program inside a VAO ?If yes, how?

Tags: opengl

So what I would normally do is:

//

...(more pseudo code here)

//shaders are already attached to a program at this point but glUseProgram is not

//called

1)bind to a vao

2) save-associate the vbos inside the vao

3) unbind the vao

//prepare to render

4) bind the vao

5) use the appropriate program with glUseProgram

6) draw

7) unbind

But is it possible to move step 5 somehow into somewhere between 1 to 3?

Comment: No, impossbile. (AFAIK)

Comment: The geometry has nothing to do with the rendering method. You can draw several VAOs with the same shader and you can draw the same VAO with different shaders. So it just does not make sense to have a shader stored in a VAO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VAO stands for *Vertex* Array Object; it defines [how vertices are stored and accessed during rendering operations](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification). It has no direct relationship to programs, and any particular VAO can be used with any compatible program.